# JPlayer + Ajax page load

Tags: ajax, callback, load, jplayer

I will try to keep this short:

How would i manage to make a unique instance of jPlayer (http://jplayer.org/) "work" after an ajax page load?

My jPlayer uses the following inline javascript code:

```
<?
    $mp3    = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'audio_mp3', TRUE);
    $ogg    = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'audio_ogg', TRUE);

?>

<?php if($mp3 && $ogg) { ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


        jQuery( '#jquery_jplayer_<?php the_ID(); ?>' ).jPlayer({
            ready: function() {
                jQuery(this).jPlayer('setMedia', {
                    mp3: "<?php echo ($mp3); ?>",
                    oga: "<?php echo ($ogg); ?>"
                    });
                },
            swfPath: "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jplayer/",
            cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_<?php the_ID(); ?>",
            supplied: "<?php if($mp3 != '') : ?>mp3, <?php endif; ?><?php if($ogg != '') : ?>oga, <?php endif; ?> all"
        });


});

</script>
```

For non unique stuff like a prettyPhoto lightbox for example i created a function (prettyPhoto(); wich i put in the callback. But i cannot seem to get this working with jplayer!

Any help would be apriciated!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the playlist add-on.

1. Create an empty player instance

   ```
   var jpplaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist({
       jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
       cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
       }, [], {
           swfPath: "/path/to/swf",
           supplied: "mp3",
           wmode: "window"
       });
   ```
2. After your AJAX page load, use the setPlaylist function to add your tracks:

   ```
   jpplaylist.add({
       title:"Song Title",
       mp3:"http://example.com/example.mp3"
   });
   ```

The full playlist specs are here: http://www.jplayer.org/latest/demo-02-jPlayerPlaylist/