# Jplayer won't show playlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jplayer

I use AJAX page loader and Jplayer.
When I link to page with playlist It doesn't show.
Else I load this page by link Example: /audio/index then everything fine.

I know that problem can me in initializer of player which has this code

```
<div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
```

What should I do? I need to play music on every page which I link via AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you read this it could help your problem....you might find it useful.

[JPlayer + Ajax page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036063/jplayer-ajax-page-load)